Why would an application run on one device but not another (both running Android 14)
I have a particular game I've been stuck on but recently switched from a OnePlus 8t+ 5G TMO to a OnePlus Nord N30 TMO.  Both of them are stock and run Upside Down Cake, but the game doesn't show up in Play Market for the N30; installing via .apk doesn't generate any error, but the app closes immediately after launching.  I haven't looked at logcat or anything yet, just wondering why there would be an interoperability issue when both are running the same OS version and are otherwise somewhat comparable in terms of hardware specs?

It would be easier to find the answer if you would name the app/ provide link to play store. If it is an older game it may be a 32bit app but more and more Android phone drop 32bit support and only support 64bit apps. Technically both CPUs of your phone support 32+64bit apps, but that require also support on OS level and for the OS the manufacturer can decide if or if not 32bit support is enabled.

@robert Huh...I guess they got delisted from G Play, so it's not because I switched phones; however, it still runs on my former phone, and not on the other.  It's called Witch Tower: Travel.

According to apkpure.com the app "com.travel.timetower" v1.14.0 supports arm64-v8a thus that shouldn't be the problem.

https://www.reddit.com/r/witchTowerFlash/comments/1cv33m5/unavailable_on_google_play_store/?chainedPosts=t3_1bfec69
